# Powershellを使ってExcelの列をコピーしたいです。

Tags: powershell

powershellを使ってExcelから指定した列をコピーしたいです。

例えばですが、
Excel1のA列、D列、F列だけを選んで、Excel2のA列、B列、C列に貼り付けるにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10172581405

Answer (score 2):

PowerShellからはCOMや.NETのオブジェクトを参照することができますので、実行するマシンにExcelが導入されている場合は

```
$app = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

// 実際のExcel処理
$app.DisplayAlerts = $false
...
```

のようにExcelのCOMインターフェイスを操作するのが良いでしょう。

上記が選択できない場合はNPOIのアセンブリ―を同梱したうえで

```
// 参照ライブラリをすべて読み込む
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("NPOI.OpenXml4Net.dll");
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.dll");
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll");
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("NPOI.dll");
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("NPOI.OOXML.dll");

$wb = New-Object NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook("excel1.xlsx");
...
```

と使用することも可能です。

それぞれのライブラリで要件を実現する方法についてはPowerShellとはほとんど関係がありませんので、VBAやC#でのサンプルなどを調べてみてください。

Answer (score 1):

Excelに関する情報は頻繁に質問にあがるようなので、最新の状況を共有します。
COM からのエクセル操作がどの言語においても苦しいように、PowerShellにおいても直接触るのは大変といわざるを得ません。

現在、PowerShellコミュニティおいては、ImportExcelというモジュールがよく利用されています。
https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

詳しい利用方法はリポジトリをご確認いただきたいのですが、PowerShell 5.0以降であればモジュールのインストールもコマンド1つで可能なので、試してみるといいと思います。

```
Install-Module ImportExcel -scope CurrentUser
```

Redditを始めとして利用方法のサンプルがあります。

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/51h101/basic_questions_about_using_importexcel/